# Blender: extrude/scale/... when using symmetry

Tags: modeling

When designing a character, I enable symmetry. However, many operations gets harder to do with symmetry. For instance, let's say I'd like to create a belt. Then, if I extrude this:

[image]

I will get:

[image]

(see how it fails on the middle axis)

Similarly, if I scale an object where a part lies in the middle line, then this part won't touch anymore the middle line, breaking the continuity of the object.

Is there a way to apply an operation like if the selection was also done on the mirror part?

Comment: Make sure you have _Clipping_ enabled in the _Mirror_ modifier. And instead of simply extruding with E it's better to use Alt+E > _Extrude Faces Along Normals_.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using a mirror modifier for your symmetry (there are other methods to edit symmetrically as well.)  A mirror modifier has an option called "clipping".  If you enable that option, it will prevent any vertices from crossing the mirror plane, and it will lock any vertices on the mirror plane to that plane:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that clipping was also locking vertices! (Btw, I can accept the answer only in 7mn)